# finding points and the derivative of a complex function at them

Tags: complex-analysis

For the function f(z)=z*Rez, indicate the points at which the derivative f'(z) exists and calculate the derivative at these points

I tried to do it like this

$Re(z) = x,  f(z) = (x + iy) * x = x^2 + ixy.$

As I understand it, the function here is differentiable on the entire complex line
Formula for finding the value of the derivativ

$f'(z) = df/dz = ∂f/∂x - i∂f/∂y,$

Found partial derivatives

$∂f/∂x = ∂(x^2 + ixy) / ∂x = 2x + i * y$

$∂f/∂y = ∂(x^2 + ixy) / ∂y = 0 + i * x.$

$f'(z) = ∂f/∂x - i∂f/∂y = (2x + iy) - i*(i * x) = 2x+iy+x=3x+iy.$

Have I found the points and their derivatives correctly?

Comment: 1. You have not explained why you claim it has a derivative on the entire complex plane. (And as a tip, it's very rare that a question would say "find the derivative at these points" if it were differentiable everywhere,  so you need a strong justification.) 2. Your formula for the complex derivative in terms of partial derivatives fails for $f(z)=z$.

Comment: @MarkS. 
Thanks for the answer, indeed the Cauchy-Riemann equations is not satisfied on the entire complex line, how can one understand at which point it is fulfilled?
$u=x^2
v=xy$
$du/dx=2x dv/dy=x du/dy=0 -dv/dx=-y$

Comment: @MarkS. 
Do I understand correctly that these conditions are met only at the point z=0 and, accordingly, the derivative will be equal to 0?